# How to properly access to array objects

Tags: php

I've a result from a webservice's query and I would like to get some values from it. It works but I have PHP notice issues, so I'm probably doing something wrong.

This is the `$items` variable content :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [response] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 275
                    [corpid] => 16107
                    [name] => default
                    [description] => 
                    [status] => ok
                    [nbSteps] => 7
                )

            [defaultItem] => 275
        )

    [error] => 
    [status] => success
)
```

So I tried something like :

```
foreach ( $items->response AS $key => $item ) {
    if ( $item->name == 'default' ){ // Line 106
        $Id = $item->id;
    }
}
```

It works, `$Id` is equal to 275 but PHP returns a notice :

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/web/dev/webservice-form.php on line 106
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT : This is the content of the $item variable (taken from the foreach loop) :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 275
    [corpid] => 16107
    [name] => default
    [description] => 
    [status] => ok
    [nbSteps] => 7
)

275
```

Please note that the '275' is a part of the result.

Comment: Which line is 106, That's where the notice is being thrown?

Comment: Best way to debug try echo the item and item->id. I think you can convert to array and use values.

Comment: `"defaultItem"->name`. `defaultItem` is not an object.

Comment: Edited and added the "Line 106"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `defaultItem` entry in your inner object. Your loop will at some point reach this and try to access `name`, which doesn't exist, because there is no object.

Should be easily solveable with `is_object()`.

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed types, one being an objects, and one an int value, try checking what each item is:

```
foreach ( $items->response AS $key => $item ) {

    if(is_object($item) && $item->name == 'default'){ // Line 106
        $Id = $item->id;
    }
    else {
         $Id = $item; // assume it's scalar value
    }
}
```

Obviously it would depend on what else you can expect on what other check you need to add in there..